# select average quantity sold per month over last 3 month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 `mysql` tables looks like this :

```
 - product(product_id, product_name)
 - order(order_id, order_date)
 - order_detail(order_detail_id, product_id, order_id, quantity)
```

I want to get the average of the quantity of products sold per month calculated over the last three months and grouping them by product

I want to select all the products (sold or not the last three months).

```
 product_name | avg_quantity_sold_per_month
--------------|-----------------------------
  product_1   | 50
  product_2   | 0
  product_3   | 78
```

I tried this query :

```
 select 
    p.product_name
  , sum(od.quantity)/3 as avg_quantity_sold_per_month
 from order o
  inner join order_detail od on o.order_id = od.order_id
  inner join product p on od.product_id = p.product_id
 where 
   o.order_date >= now()-interval 3 month 
 group by p.product_id
```

But it display only products sold last tree months, i want to select all products.

Comment: You have a typo in your query.  The order date comes from `o` not `od`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Moving average in SQL](/q/24019708/90527)", "[Computing average values over sections of date/time](/q/940550/90527)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left join`:

```
select p.product_name,
    sum(od.quantity) / 3 as avg_quantity_sold_per_month
from product p
left join order_detail od on od.product_id = p.product_id
left join orders o on o.order_id = od.order_id
    and o.order_date >= now() - interval 3 month
group by p.product_id
```

Also, try not to use reserved keywords like `order` as identifiers.

Comment: I'd join starting with the `product` table first, the left join out from there.

Comment: Your right join will be converted to inner join because of the where clause.

Comment: @GurV The order_date field does not exist in the table order_detail

Comment: @dontgav - I just modified your given query. Anyways, updated. Please please try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *all* products, you want `left join`:

```
select p.product_name,
       sum(od.quantity) / 3 as avg_quantity_sold_per_month
from product p left join
     order_detail od
     on od.product_id = p.product_id left join
     orders o
     on o.order_id = od.order_id and
        o.order_date >= now() - interval 3 month 
group by p.product_name;
```

With a `left join`, you start with the table that you want to keep.  (A `right join` leaves that important information in the *last* table which is harder follow).  The `where` condition needs to be moved to the `on` clause, so unmatched products do not get filtered out.

Note that I also changed the `group by` keys to match the keys being selected.  That is a best practice.